# Is a subset of a NP-complete language also NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete, satisfiability

For example, we know that $SAT$ is NP-complete.  However, what if we have a set $subSAT \subset SAT$.  Is $subSAT$ NP-complete?

What if we have a set $numSAT$ where $numSAT = \{ x \in SAT \; | \; |x| < 20\}$?  Is $numSAT$ NP-complete?

Comment: My hunch says yes, even if it is trivially so.

Comment: @Neil What happens then if we have a set $subSAT = \{p\}$?  This construction of $subSAT$ is such that $subSAT \subset SAT$, but it's runtime is less than polynomial.

Comment: Do languages have to be infinite in order to be in NP-complete?  My hunch is that $subSAT$ is NP-complete if $subSAT$ is an infinite language and $subSAT$ is in P if it is a finite language.

Comment: @KimmyShao: yes, a language has to be infinite to be NP-complete. A finite language is always decidable in constant time, as a Turing machine that recognizes it simply has to check a finite number of possibilities before outputting its answer.

Comment: @zarathustra I see, OK.  So is an infinite subset of an NP-complete language itself an NP-complete language?

Comment: @KimmyShao: see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is "No". For example, the empty language is a subset of any language, and is decidable in constant time, of course.

So it really depends on what subset of SAT you want to take. With your definition, $numSAT$ is in $P$, as it is a finite language (any finite language is decidable in constant time). An example of a proper subset $L$ of $SAT$ which is NP-complete is the set of boolean formulas in conjunctive normal form, where each clause has size at most $3$: this is the well-known $3$SAT problem.

Note that the converse question "If $L$ is NP-complete, is any $L'\supset L$ NP-hard?" also has a negative answer, since the full language $\Sigma^*$ is decidable in constant time. This simply says that the complexity measure does not behave well with set inclusion.

Comment: Is there any systematic way to decide if an infinite subset of an NP-complete language is itself NP-complete?

Comment: @KimmyShao: I don't think so. It was an important result of Schaefer that classified the complexity of all the subsets of $SAT$, with algebraic conditions.